# Save command run in bash function to history

Tags: bash

I have this bash function:

```
r () {
  builtin cd $HOME/rex
  rex $@
  builtin cd $OLDPWD
}
```

It is invoked with `r blahblah`.

I would like the `r blahblah` saved to my bash history. Currently, nothing gets saved to the history when I run `r blahblah`.

$HISTCONTROL is `ignorespace`

$HISTIGNORE is `r *:lb:eb*`

Comment: `ignorespace` and `r *:lb:eb*` respectively

Comment: Well, `r *` means ignore `r whatever`. Drop that (`HISTIGNORE=lb:eb*`) and `r blahblah` will be saved to history

Comment: Right. Don't know how the hell that got in there. I don't remember setting it. Nice call, though. I totally forgot about `HISTIGNORE`.

Comment: Okay, consider putting that into an answer so this question will not be listed under unanswered ones

Comment: I figured you would do that. But ok.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a malconfigured `HISTIGNORE` bash variable which told bash to ignore any commands beginning with `r *`.